# creating table insert image from file system to blob (how to)

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, phpmyadmin, blob

when im creating my table i know how to insert data into the fields but i dont know how i can insert images to blob from my file system.

```
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO pages (page_title,page_body,links,thumbs) VALUES
               ('Flash Gallery','Use Actionscript to build a Flash Photo gallery','http://www.google.com','what do i put here????'),
              ('Flash Website','Learn to create a full flash website template','http://www.google.com','what do i put here????'),
              ('XML RSS FEED','Learn to assemble XML RSS Feeds for your website','www.google.com','what do i put here????')";
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And which SQL client?

Comment: phpmyadmin, mySQL, im using xampp on localhost for now..